# ghc - duplicate sets of Compiling... messages

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I've noticed duplicate sets of "Compiling..." messages when building packages, e.g.:

```
Preprocessing library syb-0.3.7...
[ 1 of 16] Compiling Data.Generics.Basics ( ... )
[ 2 of 16] Compiling Generics.SYB.Basics ( ... )
[ 3 of 16] Compiling Data.Generics.Instances ( ... )
...
[16 of 16] Compiling Generics.SYB     ( ... )
[ 1 of 16] Compiling Data.Generics.Basics ( ... )
[ 2 of 16] Compiling Generics.SYB.Basics ( ... )
[ 3 of 16] Compiling Data.Generics.Instances ( ... )
...
[16 of 16] Compiling Generics.SYB     ( ... )
In-place registering syb-0.3.7...
Running Haddock for syb-0.3.7...
Preprocessing library syb-0.3.7...
```

I've noticed this when building in a cabal sandbox.

I'm just curious what's going on. Is it really compiling the source twice? Will this always happen? Is it related to building in a sandbox?

Comment: I think it is building once with profiling turned on and once with profiling turned off.

Comment: You can see this if you look at the file names in parentheses: the first time through, they all end in `.o`; but the second time through, they all end in `.p_o` (for Profiling Object).

Comment: Thanks - I missed that difference!

Answer (score 3):

It is really compiling the source twice. It is not related to building in a sandbox. It does not always have to happen -- you can ask cabal not to do this in its config file by toggling the `library-profiling` flag. However, it's strongly recommended that you do not do this: at the moment, cabal does not have good support for taking a dependency tree with no profiling libraries and rebuilding them all with profiling.